# How to add iads without .xib files?

Tags: iphone, xib, iad

I'm trying to add iads to the existing Baker Framework ( http://bakerframework.com/ ).
The baker framework enables you to create ebook apps with just HTML 5.

I used this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

The thing is that I don't have any xib files, and thus couldn't do the .xib steps mentioned in the tutorial.

Comment: Did you ever get a sensible answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [iAd programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

It's basically the same as with every view / view controller: instantiate and add as subview.